# jQuery element selector after appends

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, selector

I selected my elements after appends. But I can't do anything inside of the click function. Here's my code:

```
 <div class="main">

     //content is here after appends

 </div>
```

data (div-3 is hidden):

```
 <ul class="data_list">
    <li class="row">

      <div class="div-1">
          Label
      </div>

      <div class="div-2">
          <span>Text</span>
      </div>

      <div class="div-3">
           <a class="edit">
               <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
           </a>
       </div>

  </li>
  ...
```

jQuery (I want to show div-3 on mousehover and then hide the span in div-2 and then create input or show input in div-2, after that I will update the value in that input):

```
$(function(){

            $('.main').on('mouseover', '.data_list li', function () {
                $(this).find('.div-3').show();

                $('.main ').on('mouseout', '.data_list li', function () {
                    $(this).find('.div-3').hide();

                });
            });
            $('.main').on('click', '.data_list .div-3 a', function () {
                // I don't know what can I do here. 
               //I want to hide the span in div-2 and create a forminput instead. 
              //I tried $(".div-2 span").hide(); but didn't work.
            });


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the class that is assigned to that 'a' element

```
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
    //code to be executed
}
```

I would build the input into my html, set it as hidden in your css, and then show it using jquery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-2">
    <span>Text</span>
    <input class="list-input">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-input {
   display: none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.list-input').show();
```

Comment: It's not working after appends and can you tell me how can I target all without div-2? . event.target codes not working after appends.